# Problems tables and IE

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a situation with IE and a table that I am inserting from a XML document sent to it by a server, I don't understand why i can't see the table in IE but in the other browsers i can.

```
<element id='addCSS' name='reply'>
 <div id='appendCSS' main='true' father='@style_div'>
<table border='1' width="100%" >
    <col align="left" />
            <col align="left" />
            <tr>
       <th>CSS</th>
       <th>Seleccionar</th>
    </tr>
</table>
    <button id='updateCSS' father='@appendCSS'>Ok</button>
 </div></element>
```

I extract from the element the div and append it to another area, but I can't see the table. This only happens with a table, everything else is fine.

Comment: punc. tuation. ca n bevery he lp.ful.

Comment: @Roatin : Harsh and not really useful comment.

Comment: The question is: how do you insert it?

Comment: @Hogan: I must apologize. I...I don't know what got into me. *single tear*

Comment: I fixed the mistake was in the code i did a very funny thing but works, thanks all for the help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html looks fine, and displays in my version of IE.  Maybe the problem is with the JavaScript that extracts and inserts it.  Could you please post that.  Best show an example of ALL the code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I will try to check that but the code is very complex because i have to create a function that replace the importNode standard, as IE doesn't have that i have to replace that.

Comment: @hidura : ah, so the code is complex.  More complex code is more likely to have a bug.  I expect the problem is there.  You could try jslint to see if it has a simple typo.

Answer (score 1):

I inserted your code into IE7 and it worked - displayed the table.

You might have some other things that break the code and IE doesn't work.

Comment: If the code is inserted directly works perfect is when i try to taken from the xml that fails, thanks for the advice!!

Answer (score -1):

IE reqiures `<tbody>` tag

Comment: err, no.  tbody is not required.

Comment: @Hogan: sounds strange, my ie didn't display a table generated by js until i inserted a tbody tag

Comment: what do you mean generated by js?

Comment: @Hogan: i had an empty table with id, so i called a js function that created innerHTML for the table

Comment: an empty table has nothing to render -- this example had column headings.

Answer (score -1):

IE table format is

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This creates a 2 row, 2 column table.

Comment: This has nothing to do with his problem.